# Let $S\subseteq G$ for a group $G$. What is the relationship between $\langle S\rangle_G$ and ${\rm ncl}_G(S)$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, big-list

*This is a [big-list](/questions/tagged/big-list) question that I suppose could be a community wiki post. If this is too broad or otherwise a bad question, I'm sorry.*

### The Question:

> Let $S\subseteq G$ for a group $G$. What is the relationship between $\langle S\rangle_G$ and ${\rm ncl}_G(S)$?

### The Details:

Here:

- $\langle S\rangle_G$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by $S$.  It could be defined as $$\langle S\rangle_G=\bigcap_{H\le G,\\ S\subseteq H}H.$$
- ${\rm ncl}_G(S)$ is the normal subgroup of $G$ generated by $S$. It can be defined as $${\rm ncl}_G(S)=\bigcap_{N\unlhd G,\\ S\subseteq N}N.$$ Another name for this is the *normal closure of $S$*.

### Context:

I'm looking at a function $\Delta$ of groups defined in terms of *normally generating sets*. That is, I'm interested in $T\subseteq G$ for a group $G$ such that

$${\rm ncl}_G(T)=G.$$

It occurred to me that *generating sets* might be of some use. That is, I'm also interested in $U\subseteq G$ for a group $G$ such that

$$\langle U\rangle_G=G.$$

*What is the interplay between the $T$s and the $U$s?*

The best I could find was . . .

> The normal subgroup generated by a subset depends on the ambient group, unlike the subgroup generated by a subset. In other words, if $A$ is a subset of a group $H$ which is a subgroup of a group $G$, the normal subgroup generated by $A$ in $H$ may differ from the normal subgroup generated by $A$ in $G$.

. . . [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup_generated_by_a_subset).

---

*What kind of answers am I looking for?*

A list of theorems relating $\langle S\rangle_G$ to ${\rm ncl}_G(S)$. Proofs and references are optional.

---

*Since this is a [big-list](/questions/tagged/big-list) question, I will not accept an answer, unless it is somehow provably exhaustive.*

### Appendices:

As per [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4805481/let-s-subseteq-g-for-a-group-g-what-is-the-relationship-between-langle-s#comment10221692_4805481), I thought I'd add more details in these appendices.

*Appendix (Definition of $\Delta$):*

Define:

- ${\rm Conj}_G(X^{\pm 1})=\{gxg^{-1}, gx^{-1}g^{-1}\mid x\in X,g\in G\}$ for $X\subseteq G$.
- $\| g\|_S=\inf\{n\in\Bbb N\mid g=x_1\dots x_n, x_i\in{\rm Conj}_G(S^{\pm 1})\}$ for $g\in G$; and if no such $n$ exists, let $\|g\|_S=\infty$.
- $\| G\|_S=\sup\{\| g\|_S\mid g\in G\}$.
- $\Gamma(G)=\{ S\subseteq G\mid |S|<\infty, {\rm ncl}_G(S)=G\}$.

Then

$$\Delta(G)=\sup\{\| G\|_S\mid S\in \Gamma(G)\}.$$

---

*Appendix 2 (Further Motivation):*

I have some groups $G$ I would like to know $\Delta(G)$ for. I have some nice presentations and generating sets for them. My hope is that I could use those sets to bound $\Delta(G)$.

Comment: I think the question is too vague.

Comment: Okay. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve it, please, @SeanEberhard?

Comment: It's way too broad. What do you want to know specifically? What do you want to solve? What are you working on? The context you provided is blurry. Please post a specific question, then you will get an answer.

Comment: It's really akin to asking "what are the relationships between 2 and 3".

Comment: I don't think [that's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4805481/let-s-subseteq-g-for-a-group-g-what-is-the-relationship-between-langle-s?noredirect=1#comment10221693_4805481) a fair analogy. These are definitions with a similar structure, which may or may not have some useful theorems other users and myself would want to know. The function I'm looking at is part of my research, and the research, such as it is at this point, doesn't have a well-formed problem in mind; not without being scoop sensitive, @MartinBrandenburg

Comment: I could share the function, I guess, on second thoughts, because it is already linked to me via Academia.edu.

Comment: Is that better, @MartinBrandenburg?

Comment: Your $\Delta(G)$ is the maximum diameter of $G$ with respect to a normal generating set. There is a ton of literature about Cayley graphs of groups, especially finite simple groups, generating sets, normal generating sets, etc.

Comment: This is different from the diameter of the Cayley graph, since, here, the length $\| g\|_S$ of $G$ with respect to $S$ is defined in terms of conjugates of the elements of $S\cup S^{- 1}$, not just is terms of elements of $S$, @SeanEberhard

Comment: @Shaun It's the Cayley graph with respect to the generating set given by the union of the conjugates of $S$.

Comment: I did not see it that way. Thank you, @SeanEberhard!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm interested in $T\subseteq G$ for a group $G$ such that
> $${\rm ncl}_G(T)=G.$$
> It occurred to me that *generating sets* might be of some use. That is, I'm also interested in $U\subseteq G$ for a group $G$ such that
> $$\langle U\rangle_G=G.$$
> *What is the interplay between the $T$s and the $U$s?*

Let $G$ be any group, $T$ be any subset of $G$, and $$T^G=\{g^{-1}tg: t\in T, g\in G\}.$$ It is easy to check that ${\rm ncl}_G(T)=G$ iff $\langle T^G\rangle_G=G$.